# Implementing a TTY loading / waiting animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, animation, user-interface

I implemented a class to animate waiting for processes:

```
from sys import stdout, stderr
from threading import Thread


def reset_string(string):
    """Returns the reset string required to delete the provided string."""

    strlen = len(string)
    return ''.join(('\b' * strlen, ' ' * strlen, '\b' * strlen))


class TTYAnimation:
    """Text animation for interactive TTY."""

    def __init__(self, message='', animation='–\\|/', end='',
                 template='{}: {}', interval=0.1, file=stdout):
        self.message = message
        self.animation = animation
        self.template = template
        self.interval = interval
        self.file = file
        self.result = end
        self._thread = None
        self._run = False

    def __enter__(self):
        """Starts animation iff in interactive Shell."""
        self.start()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        """Stops the animation."""
        self.stop()

    def print_and_reset(self, string):
        """Prints an animation string and resets
        it after the specified interval.
        """
        print(string, flush=True, end='', file=self.file)
        sleep(self.interval)
        print(reset_string(string), flush=True, end='', file=self.file)

    def finalize(self, result):
        """Prints the terminal animation string."""
        if result is True:
            animation = str(LogLevel.SUCCESS)
        elif result is False:
            animation = str(LogLevel.ERROR)
        else:
            animation = result

        text = self.template.format(self.message, animation)
        print(text, file=self.file, flush=True)

    def run(self):
        """Runs the animation.
        Do not call this method directly,
        use start() instead.
        """
        while self._run:
            for item in self.animation:
                if not self._run:
                    break

                self.print_and_reset(self.template.format(self.message, item))

    def start(self):
        """Starts the animation."""
        if self._thread is None:
            self._run = True
            self._thread = Thread(target=self.run)
            self._thread.start()
            return True

        return False

    def stop(self, result=None):
        """Stops the animation."""
        if self._thread is None:
            return False

        self._run = False
        self._thread.join()
        self._thread = None
        self.finalize(self.result if result is None else result)
        return True
```

The full module can be found [here](https://github.com/HOMEINFO/fancylog/blob/250d306e244dc0912d6388e21106926405c16df3/fancylog.py).

I'd like to reduce the class' complexity while maintaining the current behaviour and get rid of threading, if possible.

**Invocation example**

```
from time import sleep

with TTYAnimation('Hang in there') as anim:
    sleep(5)
```